# Wireguard - no access to the internet

Tags: networking, wireguard

I have installed Wireguard on Debian 11 and created config for iPhone, and when the peers are connected, internet is not working on iPhone and also not on Debian 11 server.

Config on Debian 11:

```
[Interface] Address = 10.10.10.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING; iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51194
PrivateKey = ***(key from Debian)***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***(key from iPhone)***
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 60
```

Client config (iPhone) is the following:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***(key from iPhone)***
Address = 10.10.10.2/36

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***(key from Debian)***
Endpoint = xx.xx.xx.xx:51194
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

The connection is established, I can ping Debian 11 from iPhone and vice-versa. However, if I try to open the browser on iPhone and visit a random website, it is not working.

Also, if I try to visit some random website or IP address from Debian 11 (with curl https://xx.xx.xx.xx), it is also not working, while wg0 interface is up.

And also, I have ipforwarding enabled (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 and net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1).

Any idea?

Comment: You can make your firewall rules persistent. Linux doesn't care if an interface does not exist (yet), you can still have rules for it. This will greatly simplify your WireGuard config and also separate concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `AllowedIPs` configuration setting to specify the addresses you want to route through the WireGuard connection to that peer. You generally don't want `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` on both sides of the connection, since that means that both sides of the connection will try to route everything (ie all Internet access) through the other side of the connection (creating a circular loop).

If you only want to use the WireGuard connection to access the Debian server from your iPhone and vice versa, do this:

1. On your Debian server, set `AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/32` (the WireGuard address of your iPhone).
2. On your iPhone, set `AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.1/32` (the WireGuard address of your Debian server).

Alternately, if you want to use the WireGuard connection to route all your iPhone's Internet traffic through your Debian server, do this:

1. On your Debian server, set `AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/32` (the WireGuard address of your iPhone).
2. On your iPhone, keep `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` (all IPv4 addresses).

---

Three unrelated nits:

1. In your iPhone config, you really should have `Address = 10.10.10.2/32` instead of `Address = 10.10.10.2/36` (`/36` doesn't exist with IPv4).
2. You probably want to move your `PersistentKeepalive` setting from your Debian config to your iPhone config -- usually you want this setting on the same side that has the `Endpoint` setting (to allow the other side to initiate connections through NAT whenever the WireGuard tunnel is up).
3. You probably want to add `iptables -D FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT;` to your `PostDown` setting in your Debian config -- any iptables rules you add with `-A` or `-I` in `PostUp` you probably want to remove with `-D` in `PostDown` (otherwise you'll end up with duplicate copies of the same rule).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I wanted to route all iPhone's traffic through Debian server. So I did this:

On Debian server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING; iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE

ListenPort = 51194
PrivateKey = ***(Debian)***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***(iPhone)***
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/32
```

On iPhone:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***iPhone***
Address = 10.10.10.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***Debian***
Endpoint = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51194
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Now ping on both sides is working well, internet on Debian server also, but internet on iPhone is not working (i.e. it seems there is no default route on iPhone).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).